# How to determine whether a Thread object is the current thread in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

Suppose I have a reference to a Thread object, such as:

```
System.Threading.Thread thread;
```

If I want to determine whether the current thread is represented by this object, should the following code be used?

```
bool currentThread = (thread.ManagedThreadId == Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
```

I'm pretty sure this will work fine, but it seems strange that there wouldn't be a more direct method for checking this. Is there one?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just use [`Thread.CurrentThread`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.currentthread.aspx):

```
bool currentThread = (thread == Thread.CurrentThread);
```

Comment: Cool. I wondered if this would work. I asked because I saw someone else's code comparing thread IDs, which made me think that maybe there could be more than one Thread object related to a given thread (perhaps one maintained internally by the .NET libraries or something).

Comment: @Jeremy while reading the question, that is my concern as well. Is there ever a circumstance in which a thread can be created where `thread` somehow refers to an instance that can't be identified by `Thread.CurrentThread`?

Comment: In theory .NET does not have to match a .NET thread to an OS thread, but AFAIK the current implementations do work this way, but the documentation does stress the point that you should not rely on this being the case.